# Using a declaration quoter in a where statement

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, quasiquotes

I am implementing a DSL that is based on using standard haskell functions/combinators to build database queries. From an implementation POV I decided to represent variables in the query like this:

```hs
newtype Variable = Var { fromVar :: Text }
```

this however forces the user to write `Var "something"` quite often, so I decided to
write a quasiquoter that does this automatically.

here is an example for the DSL:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
maxQuery :: Query MAX
maxQuery = match
         ( sch `isa` "school"
         $ forWhich "ranking" `labelMatches` ran $ε)
         `get` [ran]
         `max` [ran]
    where 
        [sch,ran] = map Var ["sch","ran"]
```

what I would like it to be:

```hs
maxQuery :: Query MAX
maxQuery = match
         ( sch `isa` "school"
         $ forWhich "ranking" `labelMatches` ran $ε)
         `get` [ran]
         `max` [ran]
    where [defVars| sch ran |]
```

or something similar to this.

the quasiquoter i wrote is here:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module TypeDBTH where 
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote
import Data.List.Split
import Data.Text (pack)

mkVars :: [String] -> Dec
mkVars vars = ValD 
                (ListP (map (VarP . mkName) vars))
                (NormalB (ListE (map (\v -> AppE (ConE $ mkName "Var")
                                          $ AppE (VarE $ mkName "pack")
                                                 (LitE $ StringL v))
                                     vars)))
                []

defVars :: QuasiQuoter
defVars = QuasiQuoter { quoteDec = quoteVars }
                 --, quoteExp = expQuoteVars }

quoteVars :: String -> Q [Dec]
quoteVars = return . return . mkVars . filter (/= "") . splitOn " "

expQuoteVars :: String -> Q Exp
expQuoteVars s = return $ LetE [(mkVars . filter (/= "") . splitOn " " $ s)] (LitE $ StringL "x")
```

originally I only wrote `quoteVars`. for testing in ghci I added `expQuoteVars`.
However, removing the latter one now and trying to write

```hs
...
    where [defVars| sch ran |]
```

leaves me with two errors:

```
lib/TypeDBQuery.hs:806:1: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

because of the `where [quasiquoter]` with nothing after it

and

```
lib/TypeDBQuery.hs:807:5: error:
    • Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
        lib/TypeDBTH.hs:18:11-46: Missing field in record construction quoteExp

      Code: Language.Haskell.TH.Quote.quoteExp defVars " sch ran "
    • In the quasi-quotation: [defVars| sch ran |]
    |
807 | x = [defVars| sch ran |] 
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

how can i use the quasiquoter for a `quoteDec` instead of `quoteExp`?
is this possible at all?

I would also be open to use it like this if this is easier then:

```hs
maxQuery :: Query MAX
maxQuery = let [defVars | sch ran |] in
                $ match
                ( sch `isa` "school"
                $ forWhich "ranking" `labelMatches` ran $ε)
                `get` [ran]
                `max` [ran]
```

i took a look at the "tutorials" and info sites of wiki.haskell.org and the TH modules but could not figure out how to do this...
https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_Haskell#What_to_do_when_you_can.27t_splice_that_there
https://wiki.haskell.org/Quasiquotation
https://wiki.haskell.org/A_practical_Template_Haskell_Tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use declaration quasi quotes in top-level declarations unfortunately. From [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/template_haskell.html#extension-QuasiQuotes):

> A quasiquote may appear in place of
>
> - An expression
> - A pattern
> - A type
> - A top-level declaration

Instead of using TH, you could consider using `OverloadedStrings`:

```hs
instance IsString Variable where
  fromString str = Var (pack str)

maxQuery :: Query MAX
maxQuery = match
         ( "sch" `isa` "school"
         $ forWhich "ranking" `labelMatches` "ran" $ε)
         `get` ["ran"]
         `max` ["ran"]
```

Comment: that is quite sad;
so the only way to do it would be to construct top level declaration for all variables in this case...

Comment: I thought about this approach but I am using overloaded strings for other things and this seems to clash with `Var` unfortunately

Comment: could't this be used in a `let` pattern and expression though?
like `let [v|vars|] = [x|vars] in rest_of_function`

Comment: Yes, you could split the pattern and expression, but then you have to write the variables twice.

Comment: And maybe just using normal Haskell is not that much different then: `[sch, ran] = vars ["sch", "ran"]` using some suitable `vars` function.

Comment: yeah; that wouldn't be too nice; I converted `defVars` to produce top level declared variables now; most of the time this will be sufficient, and if not, writing it out is not extremely hard